# scikit learn TSNE transform returns strange results when applied to word vectors

Tags: python, vector, scikit-learn, transformation, word2vec

I am getting weird results when applying scikit learn's manifold t-sne implementation on word embeddings generated by word2vec.
Normally, the distance and direction of (king-queen) should be the same as (man-woman) as stated in plenty of examples on the internet.

I am sure that my word2vec model is trained correctly as I am using the Google News data set and the query of most_similar(king-man+woman) also returns queen as it is supposed to.

The plotting of the transformed 2d-vectors is also done correctly. Therefore, it must be related to the t-sne transformation from scikit learn.

I am using the following python code for transformation:

```
vecs = np.concatenate(vecs)
np_vecs = np.array(vecs, dtype='float')
ts = TSNE(2)
reduced_vecs = ts.fit_transform(np_vecs)
```

[image]

I am I doing anything wrong or is the library configuration wrong?

Comment: Ok, I have found the solution myself. As t-sne uses machine learning techniques, it has to be applied to bigger amounts of data, too, in order to return good 2d representations.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. As user1814735 stated, you can't just feed in a few points and expect good results. Feeding in a larger set of words helped tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to `iceui2`'s answer. Original [TSNE algorithm](http://siplab.tudelft.nl/sites/default/files/vandermaaten08a.pdf), is a non-linear dimension reduction technique, which tries to make sure that distribution of distances between neighbours is preserved in lower and higher dimension (neighbours in high dimension will be neighbours in lower dimension).

However, your directions are likely to get distorted, as the manifold in which points used to lie has changed drastically.

To preserve directions, I recommend using PCA for dimension reduction and then plotting.